# Need an example

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix.
Prove by explicit example that zero can be an eigenvalue of one of the matrices $A^{T}A$, $AA^{T}$ and not of the other.

Comment: To add to the answer already there: $A$ has this property iff $A$ is non-square and either $A$ or $A^T$ has a nullspace of ${0}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A=[1~ 1]$.  Then $A^TA$ is a degenerate $2\times 2$ matrix, while $AA^T=[2]$.